# Question about "It’s not about them/their being scientists."

Tags: sentence-structure, noun-phrases

In my opinion "it's not about being scientists." is good enough. But I saw this sentence on my test paper.

Is that a correct sentence? If yes, what's the function of [them] and [their] here?

Could you please give me some other examples?

Comment: Yes that is correct sentence.

Comment: Consider, “It’s not about them being scientists; it’s about the color of their hair.” “them being scientists” is a way of saying “the fact that they are scientists”.

Comment: Could you give more context? What were the sentences before this one?